# Address web path in config.yml in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

When configuring one bundle in Symfony2, I needed to set up a static path to CSS file from `web` folder, i.e. a line from *config.yml*:

```
content_css: "%path_to_web%/bundles/mybundle/css/styles.css"
```

`%kernel.root_dir%` returns the absolute root server path, but what in this case is the way of getting a **virtual** path to `web` folder? Is there any special variable for that or do I need to hard code that path?

Comment: The virtual path the the `web` folder is the root of the website usually, right? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @cheesemacfly I mean a URL to the web path, like [http://www.example.com/web/](http://www.example.com/web/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need no extra variable. The web root is defined with your webserver config. That's the way you configure the `content_css` option.

If you can reach your `app.php` (or `app_dev.php`) simple via `http://www.example.com/app.php`, then all assets are simply with the path reachable

```
content_css: "/bundles/mybundle/css/styles.css"
```

If you have exposed the whole symfony directory **(strictly not recommended)** and your `app.php` is reachable under the `http://www.example.com/web/app.php`, then simply prefix the path with `/web`.

```
content_css: "/web/bundles/mybundle/css/styles.css"
```

EDIT: Or you use a parameter in the `parameters.yml`. If you read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html) and you store your source in git or other (strongly recommended), then you have a `paramaters.yml.dist` with defaults, and every system (every developer or production server) has his own `parameters.yml`. Then add a parameter to yours and to the prods (and also to the .dist with some default):

```
parameters:
    # [...] some other parameters
    my_web_root: "/myproject/web"
```

the option looks like

```
content_css: "%my_web_root%/bundles/mybundle/css/styles.css"
```

Comment: At the localhost I test my project under certain folder, so that the path looks like `http://localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php`. After moving the project to the web, the path will look like `http://www.example.com/web/app_dev.php`. And it means that I need to change the root manually after releasing the project. Here I am trying to find an alternative way for not changing the config after the release.

Comment: First of all, don't expose your whole symfony directory to the web. Configure your DocumentRoot pointing to the `web/` directory!  
Then use the same configuration on the local machine with hostnames in the `/etc/hosts` to differ different projects.

Answer (score 4):

As the directory structure of Symfony is defined in the Standard Edition and not the Symfony2 framework, there is no special parameter to use.

`%kernel.root_dir%` is defined by using `__DIR__` in the `AppKernel` class. That's the one that should be used as the base path, you can do something like: `%kernel.root_dir%/../web/`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't control the markup rendering for that extension bundle, so with that the markup appears to become `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/var/www/project/web/bundles/mybundle/css/styles.css">`.